# Running R on Ubuntu Netbook need help with size of graphical device

Tags: r, ubuntu

I'm having small problem with the size of the graphical device when running R on ubuntu netbook.
Netbook's screen size is relatively small (1024 x 576), so when I create a chart in R say simply

```
plot(sin)
```

The graph is bigger than my screen size. I have to manually resize it.

Solution posted on [ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=891228) doesn't work for some reason. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't use Ubuntu anymore, but I think the best solution is to [put something like this](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-sig-debian@r-project.org/msg00836.html) in your .Rprofile file.

```
setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),
   function(...) grDevices::X11.options(width = 4, height = 4, pointsize = 8)
)
```

For ref., on my Mac, I have:

```
setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),
        function(...) grDevices::quartz.options(dpi = 72))
```

Comment: +1 Great tip! Although I don't have the same problem as @ilya I think this may be very useful also for other things :)